# R Shiny App - selectizeInput choices from data columns not reactive to new data

Tags: r, shiny, module

I am trying to modularize a functioning shiny app where a user uploads a file and then selects columns from the uploaded data into different roles. This worked fine before when the app had all the reactive functionality in a single file, but now with the selectizeInputs created in a module, the choices for the selectizeInputs are not reactive to changes to the uploaded data.

Here is a minimal working example. Running the app, let's say I upload a csv file with column headers "A" (numeric), "B", and "C".  I select A and B into 'y' and 'x' respectively as shown in the image below:
[image: File 1 upload with columns A and B selected]

Now, without refreshing the app, the user uploads a different csv file with column headers "D" (numeric), "E", and "F". The 'y' and 'x' inputs are still set to the columns from the previous file and the choices still reflect the columns from the previous file as well.

[image: File2 is uploaded but previous choices persist.]

Any pointers on how to get the selectizeInput choices to react to the dataframe change would be extremely helpful! Thanks. Here is the code for this example.

First, a function to get numeric columns only:

```r
#Select numeric columns of data frame
getNumCols = function(df){
  numCols = unlist(lapply(df, is.numeric))
  colnames(df)[numCols]
}
```

Input module UI function:

```r
#inputs module Input function
inputsUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns('y')),
    uiOutput(ns('x'))
  )
}
```

Input module server function:

```r
inputsServer <- function(id, data){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      ns <- session$ns
      
      numCols <- reactive({getNumCols(data)})
      cols <- reactive({colnames(data)})
      
      #Create Response Selection
      output$y = renderUI({
        selectizeInput(
          ns('y'), "Y variable", choices = numCols(), multiple = FALSE
        )
      })
      
      #Create Part Selection
      output$x = renderUI({
        selectizeInput(
          ns('x'), "X variable", choices = cols(), multiple = FALSE
        )
      })
    }
  )
}
```

And here is the code for the rest of the app:

```r
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Title"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput("file", "Upload a .csv file", accept = ".csv") 
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           inputsUI("inputs")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  userFile <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file, message=FALSE))
    input$file
  })
  
  getData <- reactive({
    read.csv(userFile()$datapath)
  })
  
  inputsServer("inputs", getData())
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you pass the dataframe stored in the `reactive` `data` to the module server instead of passing the `reactive` itself. Hence, to fix your issue pass the reactive to your server, i.e. do `inputsServer("inputs", getData)` and replace `data` in the module server by `data()`. Doing so the module server will take a reactive dependency on `getData` and will update the `selectizeInput` when `getData` changes:

Module server:

```
inputsServer <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      numCols <- reactive({
        getNumCols(data())
      })
      cols <- reactive({
        colnames(data())
      })
      output$y <- renderUI({
        selectizeInput(
          ns("y"), "Y variable",
          choices = numCols(), multiple = FALSE
        )
      })
      output$x <- renderUI({
        selectizeInput(
          ns("x"), "X variable",
          choices = cols(), multiple = FALSE
        )
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  userFile <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))
    input$file
  })

  getData <- reactive({
    read.csv(userFile()$datapath)
  })

  inputsServer("inputs", getData)
}
```

Comment: thank you.  I'm still pretty new to reactive programming, but this was an ah-ha moment. To summarize, reactive values need to be passed to the modules as arguments unresolved, and then they need to be resolved with parentheses inside the module server function.

Comment: Yep. I had the same ah-ha moment some months ago when I started to work with modules. :D